# How to create/imitate a crack in a picture in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, brush

How can I add crack to a picture in Photoshop cs5 (with or without using custom brushes) like the one below?

[image: My Image]

I tried with brushes, but it didn't look realistic.

Comment: hi guys, i really need that help. please answer my question.

Comment: Draw a jagged line with a paintbrush. Adjust opacity and blending options of the layer until it looks good.

Comment: dear DA01, would you please edit my image and show me that. how can i convert that brush to a layer and which belending options are necessary for doing that?

Comment: would you please create another crack next original carck and tell me how could you do that step by step?

Comment: I don't think the intent of this site is on demand tutorials.

Comment: You could use a Wacom Tablet or some other stylus and a regular Photoshop brush with the airbrush setting turned on to create that effect. You'd have to play with the softness and run a few passes to get it right. https://www.google.com/search?q=wacom+tablet&aq=f&oq=wacom+tablet&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j0l2j62l2.2763j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=wacom+tablet&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=0xCIUdqGBsf00QGsn4D4Bw&ved=0CDIQsxg&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.dmQ&fp=1429f1e5b9ef0936&biw=1280&bih=963

Answer (score 1):

Step by step, assuming you have used Photoshop:

- Create a new layer, and draw an irregular line using the brush tool.
- Zoom in and play with the line's opacity (you can delete or opaque certain parts), apply some smudge and also some shadows using blending styles.

Alternative, you can use a crack brush [such as this one](http://www.room122.com/photoshop/brush-set-cracks/):

[image]

The 'making it realistic' part is up to your Phothosop skills. Unfortunately, there's nothing we can do to explain this part. It comes with practice.